# In mql4 how to you clear a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: mql4

```
string trade_data = [0][4];
ArrayResize(order_data, 2);

order_data[0][0] = "a";
order_data[0][1] = "b";
order_data[0][2] = "c";
order_data[0][3] = "d";
order_data[1][0] = "e";
order_data[1][1] = "f";
order_data[1][2] = "g";
order_data[1][3] = "h";
```

Now if I want to clear the 2 indexes in this 2D array, how do I do it.
I tried:

```
ArrayInitialize(order_data, EMPTY_VALUE)
```

But it gives me this error:
'ArrayInitialize' - no one of the overloads can be applied to the function call

I just want to clear the array on each For loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
   string order_data[2][4];

   order_data[0][0] = "a";
   order_data[0][1] = "b";
   order_data[0][2] = "c";
   order_data[0][3] = "d";
   order_data[1][0] = "e";
   order_data[1][1] = "f";
   order_data[1][2] = "g";
   order_data[1][3] = "h";

   ArrayResize(order_data,3);

   order_data[0][0] = "a";
   order_data[0][1] = "b";
   order_data[0][2] = "c";
   order_data[0][3] = "d";
   order_data[1][0] = "e";
   order_data[1][1] = "f";
   order_data[1][2] = "g";
   order_data[1][3] = "h";
   order_data[2][0] = "j";
   order_data[2][1] = "k";
   order_data[2][2] = "l";
   order_data[2][3] = "m";

   //ArrayInitialize(order_data,EMPTY_VALUE);

   for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
     {
      for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
         order_data[i][j]="";
        }
     }
```

You cannot enter a string value in the ArrayInitialize method. Here are the values you can enter: char,short,int,long,float,double,bool,uint